# SQL Delete Trigger not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers, sql-update

I have the following trigger

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TG_LT_box_name_delete] 
ON [dbo].[lt_box_naming]
AFTER DELETE
AS
Set NoCount On 

update a
set used_customer_no = NULL
-- select a.* , '' as '||||', b.*
from lt_facility_ref a 
join LT_BOX_NAMING b on  b.location = ((a.facility) + '/' + a.zone + '-' + a.row_box + '-' + convert(varchar,a.seat)) 
JOIN deleted i ON b.id_key = i.id_key
```

it's a bit of a messy trigger. 
I have three tables a main table `lt_box_naming` that on insert and update store data and modify fields. it has a location field that location field is the combination of several fields from another table `lt_facility_ref`

the data looks like this

```
this is lt_facility_ref
facility    zone       row_box  seat   seat_no  used_customer_no
PRK         Balcony     B       33     17559    8626324
PRK         Balcony     B       34     15889    NULL
PRK         Balcony     B       35     17558    8626324
WZO         Orchestra   D       6      15890    NULL
WZO         Orchestra   D       7      17557    3147711


this is lt_facility_ref
id_key  customer_no type    location           seat_no
1        8626324    I     PRK/Balcony-A-1       17512
2        8626324    I     PRK/Orchestra-B-101   8527
3        3147711    C     PRK/CenterHouse-B-23  8526
4        1235878    I     WZO/TopTier-EE-1      12222
```

When a record gets inserted into `lt_box_naming` an insert trigger states using the same update code as above updates `used_customer_no` to the customer no where this account is saved and that works without issue.

on a very rare occurrence we will need to do the reverse, on delete do the same logic and update the `used_customer_no` back to NULL to free it up.

The reason for the join was because it was built like this -- the data comes from the `lt_facility_ref` and gets stored with a significant amount of other data in `lt_box_naming`

Comment: You say "it doesn't work". great, but you don't tell us why it isn't. Is there an error, it doesn't do what you expect, when you do a `DELETE` a mouse pops out the server and eats your cheese, or something else entirely? You've posted a question, great, but you haven't actually asked a question. What is your question?

Comment: there is no error, nothing happens. the delete occurs the row is no loner in my table, but the update statement doesn't update the field as i expect. (it doesn't update the field at all)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `AFTER DELETE` the record is already gone so you can't use it in a join. You can use the already referenced `DELETED` instead.

```
   update a
    set used_customer_no = NULL
    -- select a.* , '' as '||||', b.*
    from lt_facility_ref a 
    JOIN deleted i ON i.location =  ((a.facility) + '/' + a.zone + '-' + a.row_box + '-' + convert(varchar,a.seat))
```

Comment: deleted would have location in it? here is my silliness where do i find what is actually stored in deleted/inserted tables? that occur on triggers

Comment: Deleted is a reference to what was deleted - in  this case [dbo].[lt_box_naming] record(s).

Comment: This totally worked. thank you. and regarding deleted yes i understand its a reference to what was deleted but what exactly is stored and where can i find the set up/for this temporary or not temporary table.

Comment: @Elizabeth deleted is a virtual table. The structure is exactly the same as the base table that the trigger is created on. It is stored in memory (with possible spill over to disc) just like a variable or temp table.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the delete trigger is on lt_box_naming and your UPDATE statement JOIN is also on that table. Since this trigger is AFTER DELETE, that row won't exist.

Can you just remove the reference to LT_BOX_NAMING in the UPDATE statement and use the data from the **deleted** row to join lt_facility_ref?

Comment: sadly lt_facility_ref has only a used_customer_no and no id keys to join, and even if i could join on customer id the problem is each customer can have more then one record and we don't want to delete more then on.  is there a trigger that runs to save the data then do the delete?

Comment: As in Brian's answer, the **deleted** row is a representation of the lt_box_naming row that was deleted. All the fields, including location, should be present. I think that code should work.